# InternalScanner equivalent for Result.getRow()

Tags: hbase

Context: Code to be executed in an Hbase Coprocessor;

I'am trying to implement a sort of RowCount, like in the official example, but instead of simply counting the row I would like to make some stats on the "row's key".

The current implementation is something like this:
the problem is that this solution is **too** slow.

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());
HRegionInfo region = this.env.getRegionInfo();
scan.setStartRow(region.getStartKey());
scan.setStopRow(region.getEndKey());
scanner = myTable.getScanner(scan);

for (Result r : scanner) {
    String row_key = new String(tmp.getRow());
    // process row_key ..
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to get the "row id" from an InternalScanner, and if yes, how?

And also to know if it's faster iterate on an InternalScanner,
than on a ResultScanner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible,
Yes it's faster,
This is how:

```
scanner.nextRaw(values)) 
Cell c = values.get(0);
String key = new String(c.getRowArray(), c.getRowOffset(), c.getRowLength());
```

Note that if you are iterating with `while(scanner.nextRaw(values))` the net Cell will be appended to the values list (the list will not be cleared).